Como hacer que un entry se quede pegado a la esquina
Estoy tratando de hacer que una serie de preguntas (entry) se queden a la esquina derecha, pero no se como. Tal vez necesite usar una función de python que todavía no se.
Esto es lo que he intentado:
from tkinter import *

raiz=Tk()
raiz.geometry("1500x800")

miFrame=Frame(raiz, width=1200, height=600)
miFrame.pack()

raiz.title("EntryPrueba")

cuadroNombre=Entry(miFrame)
cuadroNombre.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="e")


cuadroPass=Entry(miFrame)
cuadroPass.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="e")
cuadroPass.config(show="*")

cuadroApellido=Entry(miFrame)
cuadroApellido.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="e")

cuadroDireccion=Entry(miFrame)
cuadroDireccion.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="e")

nombreLabel=Label(miFrame, text="Nombre: ")
nombreLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="e")

apellidoLabel=Label(miFrame, text="Apellido: ")
apellidoLabel.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="e")

direccionLabel=Label(miFrame, text="Dirección de casa : ")
direccionLabel.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="e")

passLabel=Label(miFrame, text="Contraseña : ")
passLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="e")



raiz.mainloop()

No entiendo porque al usar sticky no se queda a la derecha

Te recomiendo que cuando te pase este tipo de cosas les des color de fondo a tus widgets contenedores, por ejemplo:
miFrame = Frame(raiz, width=1200, height=600, bg='red')


Si te fijas tu frame posicionado con pack está centrado y ocupando el espacio mínimo necesario, que es su comportamiento por defecto. Los widgets internos del frame se posicionan en relación a éste, si los quieres en la esquina superior derecha de la ventana tendrás que posicionar el frame en ella:
miFrame.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NE)


o bien expandirlo para que ocupe toda la ventana y posicionar los widgets en esa posición, con grid lo puedes hacer con:
miFrame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
miFrame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

Esto ya requiere una pequeña aclaración.
¿Qué hace sticky?
Esta opción le indica al widget posicionado con grid que cuando sea más pequeño que la celda que ocupa se pegue a un determinado lado o esquina de la misma.
La clave es que se refiere a la celda de la rejilla, no a los bordes o esquinas de la ventana o frame contenedor.
Se ve muy claro en tu caso en los labels, si te fijas, aquellos que son más pequeños que el ancho de la columna 0 se pegan al lado derecho (E) de sus respectivas celdas. Si la celda tiene el mismo tamaño que el widget que contiene sticky no tendrá efecto alguno.
En nuestro caso con miFrame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True) le indicamos al frame que ocupe todo el espacio disponible del padre. Pero con solo esto no conseguiremos mucho, los widgets se posicionan partiendo de la esquina superior izquierda (celda con fila 0 y columna 0) y dado que las columnas ocuparan el mínimo espacio requerido (determinado por el widget más ancho de la columna) los widgets quedaran en el lado izquierdo de la ventana.
En cambio, si asignamos un peso a la primera columna con miFrame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1), ésta ocupara todo el ancho disponible que quede del padre, por lo que los widgets de la misma serán menos anchos que sus celdas y entonces sticky entra en acción pegándolos al lado derecho de cada celda:

Si solo quisieras posicionar los entries a la derecha, puedes asignarle el peso distinto de cero a la segunda columna:
miFrame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)



Gracias, ya funciona
